# My betta keeps attacking my snail!

Tags: betta, multi-pet-families, snails

I recently added a small snail to my tank and two moss balls. The snail is smaller than an an inch. However, when I got home I noticed my betta had started making a bubble nest, I'm not sure if that is relevant to this. I've had him for about two weeks now.

I put the snail in a cup floating in the water to get acclimated to the temperature and to see how my betta would react. He didn't seem to care much so after about an hour I put the snail in and they got along fine, neither cared that the other was in there.

A few hours later the snail crawled into his plant and the betta began flaring at the snail. It crawled up the wall of my tank near the bubble nest and the fish began getting more aggressive. He nipped at his shell and my fish has been acting weird since.

I had to leave for the day so I put the snail back in the floating cup so he won't get hurt, and when I came back I removed him and put the snail back in the tank. Immediately my betta began flaring his fins and nipping at his shell, knocking him down.

I'm not entirely sure what to do about this. My betta also has been frequently attacking his own reflection and biting his tail. I need good advice, thanks!

Comment: What size is the tank?

Comment: The snail is food for bettas and most other small fish.  I had a ciclid that would eat snails at night , but the tank was in my bedroom and I could hear the shell being crunched.

Answer (score 1):

Betta fish usually create bubble nests for when they're ready to mate, and wait for a female to spawn with. Betta males are very protective of their bubble nests.

It sounds like your betta got angry that your snail went to it's leaf, and then more so when the snail went near it's bubble nest, and now is attacking it.

The betta biting it's own tail sounds like it is stressed out (possibly because it thinks the snail is a danger to it/it's bubble nest). I would remove the snail from the tank.

On a separate not, you haven't said what size your tank is. If it is small, I would put it in a larger tank.